# Seeking clarity regarding callback queues and ros::spin()

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say that we have initialized 2 different `nodes` inside 2 different `main` functions. Also assume that each of these two nodes have one `subscriber` each, subscribing to the topic `topic_a`. We also have `ros::Spin()` at the end of each of these 2 `main` functions.

Would the `callbacks` corresponding to each of these 2 subscribers be pushed to the same `global queue` and `ros::spin()` call from either of the 2 nodes would `spin` the **oldest callback** from this `queue`? Or, there would be 2 `callback queues`, one for  each node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395506/seeking-clarity-regarding-callback-queues-and-ros::spin()/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2022-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-02**:
After posting an answer I must say this sounds a lot like a question on an exam, or as part of someone's homework.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2022-02-03**:
@gvdhoorn I need more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Let's say that we have initialized 2 different `nodes` inside 2 different `main` functions. Also assume that each of these two nodes have one `subscriber` each, subscribing to the topic `topic_a`. We also have `ros::Spin()` at the end of each of these 2 `main` functions.

In ROS 1, there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between *nodes* and *processes*.

So only a single node can "live" in a specific process (or: program).

Programs do not share any of their internal state by default, which would include any (global) variables.

You also -- by default -- cannot have "two different `main` functions" in a single program. The compiler will not allow you.

In my answer below I've assumed that "two different `main` functions" therefore means: "two different *programs*".

> Would the `callbacks` corresponding to each of these 2 subscribers be pushed to the same `global queue` and `ros::spin()` call from either of the 2 nodes would `spin` the **oldest callback** from this `queue`?

Due to the way operating systems isolate processes from each other, it's impossible for two nodes to share a single callback queue (or to share anything of their internal state really).

In the end, this is not really a "ROS question". Distilling it down to its essence, you ask whether `process_A` can access internal state of `process_B`. For any modern operating system, and without using special "tricks" (ie: shared memory), the answer will always be: *no*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2